# Prove $\sin x + \arcsin x > 2x$ using Maclaurin series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, trigonometry, inequality, taylor-expansion

My teacher asked us to solve this problem using the Maclaurin series, but I could not figure out how to approach..

Prove that the inequality sin x + arcsin x > 2x holds for all values of x such
that 0 < x ≤ 1.

I know that the Maclaurin series of 
sin(x) = x - $\frac{x^3}{3!}$ + $\frac{x^5}{5!}$ - $\frac{x^7}{7!}$ + ...

arcsin(x) = x + $\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{x^3}{3}$ + ($\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{3}{4}$)$\cdot\frac{x^5}{5}$ + ...

However, I do not know how to prove this using there series...Could anyone have some ideas?

Thank you!

Comment: Add the series term by term.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to prove that **all** coefficients of the sum are positive.

Notice that $\sin(x) + \arcsin(x) = 2x+\dfrac{x^5}{12}+ \dfrac{2x^7}{45}+\dfrac{5513x^9}{181440} \quad ... $

And for the domain where your equality holds, note that the Maclaurin series of $\arcsin$ only holds for $x$ in $]-1,1[$.

Comment: Yes.  You need to know all the coefficients are positive, not just the first hundred coefficients.

Answer (score 2):

For $0 < x \le 1$ we have
$$
 \sin(x) + \arcsin(x) = 2 x + \sum_{n=2}^\infty \left(\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!} +  \frac{1 \cdot 3 \cdots (2n-1)}{2 \cdot 4 \cdots (2n)} \frac{1}{2n+1} \right) x^{2n+1}
$$
because the $x^3$ terms cancel. Therefore it suffices to show that
$$
 \frac{1 \cdot 3 \cdots (2n-1)}{2 \cdot 4 \cdots (2n)} \frac{1}{2n+1} > \frac{1}{(2n+1)!}
$$
for $n \ge 2$. This is equivalent to
$$
\frac{1 \cdot 3 \cdots (2n-1)}{2 \cdot 4 \cdots (2n)} \cdot (2n)! > 1
$$
or 
$$
\bigl( 1 \cdot 3 \cdots (2n-1) \bigr)^2 > 1 \, ,
$$
which is obvious.

Answer (score 2):

For $0\le x\le1$ we have

$$\sin x\ge x-{1\over6}x^3\ge0\quad\text{and}\quad\arcsin x\ge x+{1\over6}x^3+{3\over40}x^5\ge0$$

which imply

$$\sin x\arcsin x\ge x^2+\left({3\over40}-{1\over36} \right)x^6-{1\over80}x^8=x^2+\left(34-9x^2\over720\right)x^6\ge x^2$$

By AGM we have

$${\sin x+\arcsin x\over2}\ge\sqrt{\sin x\arcsin x}\ge x$$

Remark: As Martin R astutely observes in comments, as soon as you have $\sin x\ge x-{1\over6}x^3$ and $\arcsin x\ge x+{1\over6}x^3$, you have $\sin x+\arcsin x\ge2x$, so tacking another (nonnegative) term onto the arcsine series, taking the product and using AGM is wholly unnecessary.  I failed to notice this because I was approaching things backwards: I had decided to see if AGM could be used and then worked out how much of the two series were needed to arrive at the desired inequality.

The inequality $\sin x\ge x-{1\over6}x^3$ for $0\le x\le1$ can be seen from the fact that the series for $\sin x$ is an *alternating* series of *decreasing* terms.

Comment: You don't need the product or AGM. Adding the first two inequalities already gives $\sin(x) + \arcsin(x) \ge 2x + \frac{3}{40}x^5 > 2x$ (assuming that $\sin(x) \ge x - \frac 1 6 x^3$ is known).

Comment: @MartinR, you are right. I was working backwards in my thinking, wondering what you'd need to know about the series for the sine and arcsine in order to use AGM, and was blind to the obvious. I'll add a remark to that effect.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: A nicer representation of the arcsin series is 
$$\arcsin(x) = \sum_{n = 0}^\infty \frac{1}{4^n} {2n \choose n} \cdot \frac{x^{2n + 1}}{2n + 1}$$
Since both $\sin(x)$ and $\arcsin(x)$ are both odd, we can look at the coefficients on all the odd-degree terms. Can you prove that for all $n \geq 1$, 
$$\frac{1}{4^n} {2n \choose n} \cdot \frac{1}{2n + 1} \geq \frac{1}{(2n + 1)!} \iff \frac{1}{4^n} {2n \choose n} \geq \frac{1}{(2n)!}$$ 
This would prove all coefficients of terms with degree greater than $1$ in the expansion of $\arcsin(x) + \sin(x)$ are positive, and thus $\sin(x) + \arcsin(x) = 2x + C$, where $C$ is strictly positive.

Comment: The series for $\arcsin x$ is obtained by term-by-term integration of the (binomial) series for $1/\sqrt{1-x^2}$.

Comment: In fact, since $\binom{2n}{n}$ is the largest binomial coefficient in its row of Pascal's triangle, it is at least $\frac{4^n}{2n+1}$, never mind $\frac{4^n}{(2n)!}$.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the infinite expansion
$$\sin (x)+\sin ^{-1}(x)=2x+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\frac{4^{-n} (2 n)!}{(2 n+1) (n!)^2}+\frac{(-1)^n}{(2 n+1)!} \right)x^{2n+1}$$
If $n$ is even, the coefficient in brackets is positive.
So, for the case where $n$ is odd, we need to prove that the coefficient is positive $\forall n$ that is to say that
$$\frac{4^{-n} (2 n)!}{(2 n+1) (n!)^2}>\frac1{(2 n+1)!}\implies b_n=\frac{4^{-n} (2 n)! (2 n+1)!}{(2 n+1) (n!)^2}>1 $$ Simplifying
$$b_n=\frac{4^{-n} (2 n)! (2 n)!}{ (n!)^2}$$ Take logarithms, use Stirling approximation, go back to exponentials to show that
$$b_n \sim  2\left(\frac {2n} e\right)^{2n}\exp\left(-\frac 1{12n} \right)$$ So, all coefficients are positive.

Comment: That is an approximation (or asymptotic equality) for $b_n$. Does that really prove that *all* coefficients are positive?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

As all coefficients of the development of $\arcsin x$ are positive, it is obvious that $\arcsin x>x$.

This cannot be said of the series for the sine, which alternates.

Now you can infer that the sum will work, if the respective coefficients of the arc sine compensate the negative coefficients of the sine.